# Create nested collapsible tables using Angular

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm displaying a table that consists of all of the events a specific team as attended in a given year. Each row of the table gives some general stats for a single event (seed, placement, etc). When I click on any given row, I want to expand a nested table that shows all the games from that specific event.

I'm having some issues with the formatting. Right now when I expand the new table, it reformats the parent table in a strange way and all of the nested table columns only stretch across the first  of the parent table. How can I make it the same width of the parent table?

[Here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-smvq3g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

and here is a screenshot of the more pretty formatted table in case the stackblitz example is hard to see.

Collapsed: [image]

Expanded:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place your nested table in a tr and td with a colspan="4"

See the updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wnr2qn-nested-table

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!! Next step is to animate it so it glides in and out...time to google CSS tricks :)

Answer (score 1):

Full code. Just change ng-container for a tr.

Full code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kutwtd

Example live: [Here](https://angular-ivy-kutwtd.stackblitz.io/)

**IMAGES EXAMPLE**

[image]

[image]